# Importing a schema into another file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I am trying to import Punishment schema into my guild.js but I don't know how to import it.

As you can see, I have punishments.js, but I need to include punishmentSchema into guild.js because it relies on it

### Punishments.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const punishmentType = Object.freeze({
  WARN: "Warn",
  BAN: "Ban",
  MUTE: "Mute",
});

const punishmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String,
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: Object.values(punishmentType),
  },
});

exports.punishmentSchema = punishmentSchema;
exports.Punishment = mongoose.model("Punishment", punishmentSchema);
```

### Guild.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const guild = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  prefix: String,
  punishments: [Punishment],
});

const Guild = mongoose.model("Guild", guild);
module.exports = Guild;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a regular `require`:

```
const {Punishment} = require('./Punishments');
```

Comment: i did that and i got an error that said

Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `punishments`. See bit.ly/mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.